# sed on sun solaris

Tags: sed, solaris

I am try to do the following on sun solaris

```
    sed   "/ADDRESS/a \
           PROTOCOL"  file  > NEW_file
```

but I get:

sed: command garbled: /ADDRESS/a        PROTOCOL

why (on linux its work) ,

is it possible to support syntax that work on linux and on sun

lidia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's another way, use nawk

```
nawk '/ADDRESS/{$0=$0" PROTOCOL"}1' file
```

Comment: not good I want to add the PROTOCOL under the line ADDRESS not after the word ADDRESS

Comment: then add a newline "\n". Not that hard to try it out yourself! You have been asking a lot of questions about shell scripting, you should know how to use awk by now!!!! I am not going to spoonfeed you all the way..!!

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is a Gnu sed extension. It works on Gnu/Linux because you have a Gnu userland with it. It works on Solaris if Gnu sed is installed on it. It might be in /usr/gnu/bin/sed, /usr/sfw/bin/gsed or somewhere else, depending on the Solaris release you are using.